# Pushing PHP Array in a JS Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

This is my first post so please apologize me if it's not that good.

This is my "area_chart.charts.php" where the Array is :

```
$data=array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $chartDate = date("d/m", strtotime($row['created_at']));
  $chartResultats = $row['traitements'];
  $chart = array("chartResultats" => $chartResultats,"chartDate" => $chartDate);
  array_push($data, $chart);
}
```

**JSON Response: https://prnt.sc/1whxygm**

I'm trying to retrieve the data to use it with Chart.JS using Ajax, but the way i'm doing it doesn't work. Do someone have an idea how to do it?

The result i want is :

```
chartResultats: [10, 30, 20]
chartDate: ["16/10", "16/10", "16/10"]
```

I tried to use Ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
url:"./inc/charts/area_chart.charts.php",
method:"GET",
success:function(data)  {
console.log(data);
chartResultats = data["chartResultats"];
chartDate = data["chartDate"];

// Area Chart

var ctx = document.getElementById("chartResultats");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [chartDate],
    datasets: [{
      data: [chartResulats],
    }],
```

and Fetch but it didn't succeded. My chart is returning me underfined.

Can you please help me or clarify me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not say how you output the `$data` array to make it available to AJAX.

To output `$data` as JSON, you have to end your script with,

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
print json_encode($data);
exit();
```

You can then use your browser to open the charts.php page and inspect the JSON output.

To have the JSON you require, however, you need something like,

```
$data=array(
    'chartResultats' => array(),
    'chartDate' => array(),
);

foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data['chartDate'][] = date("d/m", strtotime($row['created_at']));
  $data['chartResultats'][] = $row['traitements'];
}

header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
print json_encode($data);
exit();
```

The output should be like,

```
{
    "chartResultats": [10, 30, 20],
    "chartDate": ["16/10", "16/10", "16/10"]
}
```

In the code you posted, you create at each iteration a new dictionary with one chartResultats r and one chartDate d (let us call this `{ r: 1, d: 1 }`):

```
$chart = array("chartResultats" => $chartResultats,"chartDate" => $chartDate);
```

and then you push this object onto data, getting an array of such objects:

```
array_push($data, $chart);
```

So your data is `[ { r: 1, d: 1 }, { r: 2, d: 2 }, ... ]` (an array of dictionaries) instead of being `{ r: [ 1, 2, ... ], d: [ 1, 2, ... ] }` (a dictionary of two arrays).

**Note.**

I think that this way, you already formatted correctly the two arrays; there is no need to format them *again* in the success callback. So, try

```
data: {
   labels: data["chartDate"],    // Not [chartDate]
   datasets: [{
      data: data["chartResultats"],  // Not chartResultats
   }],
```

Comment: I already done this, i just didn't uploaded all the file, but it's already in JSON type because it gives me the response. You can see it on the screenshot! :)

Comment: Sorry: in "the JSON I need" you did not include braces or quotes; in the JSON you generated and posted, the code pushes the data the wrong way, as objects inside an array. You need to add to entries in a dictionary (see the second part of this answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It now don't display undefined anymore. It's showing me dates however not the way it must be, and the 'resultats' don't display too.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1wivl38

Comment: @newcomerindev hmm, I think you might have overdone the subscripting. Adding note.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use echo

`echo json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 0):

LSerni's answer will probably lead to solving the issue as it addresses what I see as the most important thing missing from the premise in order to solve the issue `chart is returning undefined`.

Beyond that I see that when you would get a response, in your `$.AJAX.success` function is that you are only doing a single assignment which will probably fail, because `data.chartResultats` and `data.chartDate` are undefined. Instead `data` is an array of objects that have both `chartResultats` and `chartDate`.

```
chartResultats = data["chartResultats"];
chartDate = data["chartDate"];
```

Therefore, one solution to produce your intended output(

```
chartResultats: [10, 30, 20]
chartDate: ["16/10", "16/10", "16/10"]
```

) is to iterate over the data. Here is one implementation:

```
var chartResultats = [];
var chartDate = [];
data.forEach(function(record){
  chartResultats.push(record.chartResultats);
  chartDate.push(record.chartDate);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

So i did it like you said, and now it doesn't display me anything. :/

Comment: Did you solve this issue? What doesn't display? Did you check the contents of `chartResultats` and `chartDate` ? If you also implemented LSerni's solution for your PHP code to print the JSON, then what I said was not necessary.